# float() argument must be a string or a number

Tags: python-2.7

I'm creating a new program in python that searches for the numbers outside of the function but it gives me this error:

```
float() argument must be a string or a number
```

This is my code:

```
    def CalcKm(self, km, time):
        if not km:
            return 0

        kmCalc = int((round(float(km) * float(time)) / 100) - .5) + int(int((round(float(km) * float(time)) / 100) - .5) > 0)

        if kmCalc <= 0 and km > 0:
            km = 1
        else:
            km = kmCalc

        return km

        .....

    def Information(self):
        km = 1
        time = 2
        if 0 == time:
            continue

        show = self.CalcKm(km, time)
        self.Show()
```

Comment: The `float` code looks fine - however the indentation (especially of the method call `self.CalcKm` seems odd. Can you post some more of the class structure?

Comment: Just edited the post, check it out

Comment: I don't get any errors from the `float` - though I do get them from the `continue` not being in a loop. Changeing `continue` to `pass and it runs without errors: https://eval.in/978985 can you confirm that the error actually relates to this code block?

Comment: Well, I fixed by puttin the `kmCalc = int((round(float(km) * float(time)) / 100) - .5) + int(int((round(float(km)` on `def Information`